# Recover an accidentally initialized Bitlocker partition

Tags: data-recovery, bitlocker, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, file-recovery

**NOTE:** 
Before you downvote or mark as duplicate, please note that i DID look around and while i found similar issues on stackexchange and elsewhere, I wasn't able to go very far.

In short, I have a 1TB HDD which contained only 1 partition that filled the first 500GB. That partition was encrypted with Bitlocker, for which I still have both the password and recovery Key.

Through a series of catastrophic fails on my behalf, I have managed to execute the diskpart `clean` command on that drive and also later `Initialize` the HDD with Disk Management.

I've tried many recovery tools but none gave me any of the recent files i'm looking for, most likely because they're encrypted.

Later I came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/317092/need-to-recover-an-accidentally-formatted-i-e-wiped-out-hard-drive) which set my hopes up, but then when I followed the steps, i'm still unable to open the created `img` file and access the data.

So my questions are:

- How likely is it that all or most my data is still there?
- Do I still have any hopes of recovering it? Even partially (as in, not all the files, but not partial/non readable files)
- Is there perhaps a way to recreate the partition while leaving the data intact and tricking windows into thinking it's a "current" bitlocker encrypted drive so i can unlock it with the passphrase?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have tried to recover the data, and have failed to do that, there isn't much you can do.  The data is encrypted, so you would have to recover at the very least the required partition header, and even if you did that, you would still have to recover the data in its entirety.

Comment: does the partition head get erased with either the `clean` or `initialize` commands?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  What does the partition head have to do with data?  Do you mean **header**, you have tried to recover the data, and failed so in this case the **header** has been deleted.

Comment: yes sorry i meant "header". Umm so i'm confused, if the header is in fact gone, how come a tool such as M3DataRecovery is able, without any user input, to detect that the disk has a deleted Partition, with the correct size, AND also say that it's a Bitlocker encrypted partition?

Comment: PS: That tool is able to detect the deleted partition correctly (unlike others) but it gets stuck and says "Data not found" as soon as I give it the bitlocker recovery key

Comment: You have to put the header back on the drive then mount the drive within Windows so you can then run data recovery on ot