# Just formatted my harddrive by accident

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover folders from formatted drive](https://superuser.com/questions/295497/how-to-recover-folders-from-formatted-drive)

I was trying to format my USB drive, and somehow, without paying attention, I did a quick format of my backup drive which I use for storage. I have lost everything. Is there a way of restoring this  drive?

I'm using Windows 7, 32-bit, on an Asus laptop. What's my best course of action from here?

Comment: Back in XP , we would just run an Unformat, using a small utility program (I do not remember the name), and it was all back again. As long as you don't mess with it in other ways, unformat and make sure that the cluster size and partition table is similar, then copy the data off, then reset it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Easeus one to recover everything http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-formatted-partition.htm

Comment: bugger was hoping for something free... I have tried recuver but it keeps crashing..  I have tried a few other things but they are all pretty painfull to us.