# Used an external HDD for a Windows install on a laptop, now all data gone/unallocated; best software/method to recover it?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, bitlocker

Recently I have used my 5TB external HDD to re-install Windows on a laptop I am selling. I created a separate partition to boot the windows installation on the laptop, well I screwed up by ignoring the warnings thinking it will only "wipe" the boot partition and now my data from partitions I was using is "unallocated".

This disk had **2 partitions** (except the boot one), main one with most of the disk size and a BitLocker password encrypted one of about a 100GB. Main partition was filled with ~2.5TB of data and a BitLocker partition was filled up with ~50GB of data.

Now when I open the disk management tool in Windows it shows it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mJiE.png), "New volume" is completely empty and I assume the "Unallocated" space is where my data is, and I need to recover it, also when I right click on the unallocated space the options to create a new simple volume are greyed out.

How would I be able to recover the data and especially how can I recover the encrypted BitLocker partition properly? What software could I use (highly preferably free, or max up to 50€) that would be able to recover the data and divide it into its original partition properly?

Comment: Please use search before posting - see https://superuser.com/questions/295497/how-to-recover-folders-from-formatted-drive and https://superuser.com/search?q=recover+format+drive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover folders from formatted drive](https://superuser.com/questions/295497/how-to-recover-folders-from-formatted-drive)

Comment: @Tetsujin I did indeed use search, none of my findings fit my problem.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No.

Comment: 1. This is not the site for software recommendations -- try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . 2. Regrettably, you likely cannot recover the data yourself, even with commercial software, and almost certainly, anything in the BitLocker partition is unrecoverable, except possibly by state agencies such as NSA or FSB RF.